# awesome_nested_set with optgroup labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, optgroup

I am using the awesome_nested_set gem located here https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set. I would like to make the parent categories optgroup labels but am at a loss on how to make that happen or if it is even possible. Is there an example somewhere of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not the most efficient way to do this, but it met the requirement of the task.

```
  <select name="category_id" data-placeholder="Select a Category" class="chzn-select">
     <option value=""></option>
     <% @cats.each do |cat| %>
     <optgroup label="<%= cat.name %>">
        <% cat.children.each do |child| %>
        <option value="<%= child.id %>"><%= child.name %></option>
        <% end %>
     </optgroup>
     <% end %>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I had the same question and solved it by using a helper method according to https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/blob/master/lib/awesome_nested_set/helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def grouped_nested_set_options(class_or_item, mover = nil)
    if class_or_item.is_a? Array
      items = class_or_item.reject { |e| !e.root? }
    else
      class_or_item = class_or_item.roots if class_or_item.respond_to?(:scope)
      items = Array(class_or_item)
    end
    result = []
    group = []
    items.each do |root|
      root.class.associate_parents(root.self_and_descendants).map do |i|
        if i.level == 0
          group = []
          group.push yield(i)
          group.push []
          result.push group
        else
          if mover.nil? || mover.new_record? || mover.move_possible?(i)
            group[1].push [yield(i), i.primary_id]
          end
        end
      end.compact
    end
    result
  end
end
```

That way you can just use grouped_nested_set_options instead of nested_set_options and you can still use rails' form helpers for generating the html.